# function in onaftersave is called twice always

Tags: angularjs, ajax, x-editable

When I save the edited values of a table to server side using xeditable, the function in "onaftersave" is called twice because of which two ajax calls of same type are hitting the service. I am using "$submit" in save button and "onaftersave" in the form table. Any help on this would resolve my issue. Thanks in advance!

```
<form editable-form name="vm.weektableform" onaftersave="vm.saveTable()"         oncancel="vm.cancelTable()">
<table>
<tbody ng-repeat="row in data">
<tr>
<td >
<span editable-number="row.dayPack" e-form="vm.weektableform"  onbeforesave="vm.checkNumber(row,row.dayPack,$data)"">{{row.dayPack}}</span></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<button class="saveButton" data-ng-click="vm.weektableform.$submit()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Show some code... I actually just wrote an app using this last week and didnt have any problems.

Comment: <form editable-form name="vm.weektableform" onaftersave="vm.saveTable()" oncancel="vm.cancelTable()">

<table>

  <tbody ng-repeat="row in data">

   <tr>

     <td ><span editable-number="row.dayPack" e-form="vm.weektableform"  onbeforesave="vm.checkNumber(row,row.dayPack,$data)"">
{{row.dayPack}}</span></td>

   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>

<button class="saveButton" data-ng-click="vm.weektableform.$submit()">Save</button>

Comment: can u cleanly edit this and add it to the question - this is unreadable

Comment: seems like this - data-ng-click="vm.weektableform.$submit()" and this -  onaftersave="vm.saveTable()"  are a source of your trouble - try removing one...

Comment: If I remove "vm.weektableform.$submit()" , the function in "onbeforesave" which checks validation is not working and if I remove savetable() function, data is not saved to server side

Comment: @Sten Muchow can you tell why there is a problem with those two functions?

Comment: I am not completely sure from a brief glance at the code it seemed the submit was potentially firing the onaftersave but its just an off the top of my head feeling... Will need to have a closer look, but i dont have the time at this moment with work

Comment: try adding type="button" in button